# Add sticker and resize with Pinch in or Pinch out in react Native: Picture Editing Application

Tags: react-native, image-editing

I'm Trying to built a picture editing application and so far im able to select a picture from gallery and able to add stickers on it (e.g hair styles, eyebrows, nose etc) but im not able to resize these stickers according to picture
i dont know which package to use and how to make it work, please help

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow, please post your code so far, lots of info here to help on writing a good question https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

You can use `react-native-stickers` or in your solution use `react-native-gesture-handler`.